# Using OpenCV in ARToolkit5 (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, opencv, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I wanted to know if anyone has managed to use OpenCV in the example codes given by ARToolKit5. I was wishing to use it mainly in the nftSimple example. But since the artoolkit5 code is written in C and using opencv in C is not easy, was wondering if anyone has any ideas, or could give me some sample code to start off with. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx/tree/master/Source/ARX/OCVT this is the newer image tracker based on OpenCV and using jpeg image files.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response! Being new to this, I am not exactly sure as to how I should build the tracker program. Would you be able to help with that?